# How execute a class with main method with a Jbutton

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-8

I want to call and execute a class with main method from another class which has main method too by clicking on a  Jbutton.
The class of  Example1 wich has main method run perfectly stand alone:

```html
import org.nlogo.app.App;
public class Example1 {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    App.main(argv);
    try {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(
    new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          App.app().open("C:/Users/fmar825/Desktop/fire.nlogo");
        }
        catch(java.io.IOException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }}});
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

But when I call it from another class to be execute with clicking on Jbutton.

```html
  private void okbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    
        Example1 object=new Example1();
        try {
               object.main(new String[0] );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
    }
```

I got following Error message.

```html
ava.lang.Error: Cannot call invokeAndWait from the event dispatcher thread
 at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1289)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1282)
 at org.nlogo.awt.EventQueue$.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.scala:19)
 at org.nlogo.app.App$.main(App.scala:150)
 at org.nlogo.app.App.main(App.scala)
 at Example1.main(Example1.java:4)
 at User.okbtnActionPerformed(User.java:995)
 at User.access$1600(User.java:31)
 at User$19.actionPerformed(User.java:604)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
 at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.nlogo.window.RuntimeErrorDialog.suppressJavaExceptionDialogs(RuntimeErrorDialog.java:63)
 at org.nlogo.app.App.handle(App.scala:779)
 at org.nlogo.util.Exceptions$.handle(Exceptions.scala:21)
 at org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$7.uncaughtException(App.scala:305)
 at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1057)
 at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1052)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.processException(EventDispatchThread.java:223)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:215)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `invokeAndWait` to `invokeLater`

Essentially what's happening is, your `JButton` is executing the `ActionListener` from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, this is just how it works.  When you call `Example1.main`, it attempts to invoke the `Runnable` within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, but block the current thread (which is the EDT) until it completes.  This is, obviously unachievable and in order to prevent a possible thread dead lock, `invokeAndWait` will throw an exception.

You "could" also change the code in `Example1` to something like...

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            App.app().open("C:/Users/fmar825/Desktop/fire.nlogo");
        } catch(java.io.IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
    runnable.run();
} else {
    try {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(runnable);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }    
}
```

Which checks to see if the current thread is the EDT and if so, simply calls the `run` method of the `Runnable` directly, otherwise it calls `invokeAndWait`.  This will better mimic the original behavior when called from within the context of the EDT

**Runnable example**

It works just fine for me...

### `Parent` (GUI) class...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Parent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Parent();
    }

    public Parent() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton makeItSo = new JButton("Make it so");
            makeItSo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Child.main(new String[0]);
                }
            });
            add(makeItSo);
        }

    }

}
```

### `Child` (other `main`) class

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Child {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I'm a banana");
            }
        };

        if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
            System.out.println("Execute within the EDT");
            runnable.run();
        } else {
            try {
                System.out.println("Invoke and Wait");
                java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(runnable);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I changed it to invokeLater, but still i got same error.

Comment: Not possible, unless there is another `invokeAndWait` somewhere else in the code

Comment: when I changed  the code to what you recommend it says that there is not EventThread Package.

Comment: I got the same Error Message .

Comment: Are you re-compiling the classes?  Have you tried putting in output statements to test that the correct code is been called? Have you tried debugging the code?

Comment: there is no bugs on the code I just re-complied and got same error message.

Comment: I made the GUI using Java swing and I cannot edit it.

Comment: So?  You can edit the `main` method?  That's all you need to do.  I just added a runnable example to demonstrate the fact that the concept works, that's all